# Как сконвертировать XML в CSV?

Tags: xml, csv, конвертация

Есть выгрузка товаров в формате XML (commerceML 2 похоже).
Мне нужно сконвертировать её в CSV выдернув нужные данные: название, некоторые свойства и разложить по колонкам.
Может кто-нить знает подходящий для этого софт? Что бы один раз настроил шаблон, а дальше по потребности скармливаешь ему XML, а он на выходе CSV отдает.

Иначе придется на PHP писать, но вдруг что-то готовое есть.
On-line сервисы не походят.
Ерунду какую-то выдают.

Comment: Думаю, надо как минимум показать пример XML и требуемый для него выходной CSV. 3-5 записей...

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте пожалуйста про XSLT. Это специальный синтаксис трансформации xml данных. Вам понадобится написать шаблон трансформации. Программ и примеров много на различных языках.

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky благодарю.